# "Bild" zu "visualisiert" ist wie "Ton" zu...?

Tags: single-word-request, verb, analogy

Ich bin gerade auf der Suche nach einem schönen Wort um zu sagen, dass etwas per Audio-Wiedergabe vermittelt wurde.

Wenn es um ein Video oder eine Graphik ginge, würde ich *visualisiert* verwenden. Was muss ich im Falle von synthetisierter Sprachausgabe schreiben?

Comment: _hörbar gemacht?_

Comment: *Visualisieren* ist noch ein bisschen mehr als *sichtbar machen*, finde ich. Schöne Frage.

Comment: Kann es da wirklich was geben? Die Prozesse sind ja eigentlich nicht parallel: Beim Visualisieren wird etwas meistens Abstraktes, "Unsichtbares" sichtbar gemacht, vom Gedanklichen/Sprachlichen ins Bildliche überführt. Bei dem, das Du suchst, geht es ja nicht um eine richtige "Versprachlichung", sonder nur um einfaches "Vorlesen" - oder verstehe ich Dich falsch? - Im Übrigen finde ich "hörbar machen" einen schönen Ausdruck, den man unterstützen sollte - ich werde versuchen ihn ab jetzt einmal monatlich anzuwenden :)

Comment: Naja, es geht um mehr als nur etwas vorzulesen, da in meinem Fall ein Programm eine Navigationsstruktur - die wiederum in Abhängigkeit des Aufrufkontexts des Links erstellt wird - erklärt wird.
Also hörbar machen passt IMHO nicht so ganz.

Comment: Wäre es keine Computerstimme, würde ich "einsprechen" sagen. Hier passt das aber auch nicht recht, weil mein Bild im Kopf dann einen echten Sprecher in einem Studio enthält.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nach Deinem Kommentar

> Naja, es geht um mehr als nur etwas vorzulesen, da in meinem Fall ein
>   Programm eine Navigationsstruktur - die wiederum in Abhängigkeit des
>   Aufrufkontexts des Links erstellt wird - erklärt wird. Also hörbar
>   machen passt IMHO nicht so ganz. – schlingel Jun 15 at 16:39

fürchte ich, dass Du da kein griffiges Wort finden wirst. Wenn ich Dich richtig verstehe, handelt es sich sozusagen um eine Art Anleitung, richtig?

Was ist da gegen "erklären" einzuwenden? Klingt so, als ob genau das gemacht würde, oder?

Je nachdem was da tatsächlich vor sich geht, ginge vielleicht auch:

> Das Programm spricht Ihnen die Navigationsschritte vor.

oder Du formulierst irgendwas mit "gesprochene Erläuterung" oder so.

P.S.: Wär interessant zu erfahren, wie Du's dann letztlich gelöst hast! :)

Comment: Ich hab' dann "gesprochene Erläuterung" genommen. Ist nicht ganz das was ich mir gewünscht habe, aber mir gefällt das Wort Erläuterung xD.

Comment: @schlingel: Was lange währt, wird endlich gut :)  Vielen Dank für das Update!

Answer (score 8):

Im Bereich von Multimedia-Programmierung spricht man auch von [*Sonifikation*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonifikation) bzw. *Verklanglichung*. Falls es sich speziell um Umwandlung von geschriebenen Text in Sprachausgabe handelt, ist der Begriff *Sprachsynthese* gängiger.

Answer (score 5):

Ein Ton ist natürlich nicht irgendwie analog zum Bild, sondern ein Bild sagt mehr als tausend Worte - dem Ton entspricht ein Farbklecks oder -tupfer, dem Bild ein Musikstück oder ein gesprochener Text.

Ein Musikstück kann man **intonieren**. Eine synthetische Sprachausgabe, wenn es nur darum geht einen Text durch tts/mbrola zu jagen; ein Prozeß, bei dem der kritische Teil der Intonierung ja gerade nicht gelingt, Ausdruck ins Geräusch zu legen, sondern allenfalls notdürftig Satzanfang und Ende betont werden und ein Fragezeichen vermittelt wird, ... - keine Ahnung.

**Vertonung** gibt es noch als Ausdruck, wenn man etwa aus einem Gedicht ein Lied macht, womit man eher die Arbeit des Komponisten bezeichnet. Intonierung dagegen wäre die Umsetzung durch Musiker/Sänger, auch Interpretation.

Beim Sprachsynthesizer kann man wohl von **abspulen/abspielen** sprechen, vielleicht auch **prozessieren, compilieren**.

Comment: Alles nicht ganz alltagstauglich -- ausser Vertonung/vertonen.

Comment: Was meinst Du mit "nicht alltagstauglich"?

Comment: Naja, man kann sagen "Man könnte das visualisieren, indem man...", dann versteht das jeder. (Naja.) Wenn man im entsprechenden akustischen Fall sagt "Man könnte das intonieren/vertonen/abspulen/prozessieren/compilieren", schaut man Dich an wie eine Acht. Insofern fehlt mir "hörbar machen".

Comment: Man führt ja eine Konversion nicht so, dass man mit dem Satz beginnt "Man könnte das intonieren/abspulen/..." sondern hat ja einen Kontext in dem man das sagt.`Auf dem Geburtstag spulte die Erdbeertorte "Happy Birthday" ab; ja, die Erdbeertorte selbst.`

Comment: Vor allem wenn es um Musik geht, ist vertonen sehr treffend. +1

Answer (score 4):

Die Antwort, die ich gebe, wurde schon in einem Kommentar erwähnt:

> hörbar machen

Der Ausdruck ist zwar stilistisch nicht besonders schön, aber trifft die Bedeutung, die *visualisieren* für Bilder hat, für Töne am besten.

Comment: hörbar machen gefällt mir persönlich nicht, da mit "machen" ein Wort verwendet wird das genauso allgemein wie farblos ist.

Answer (score 3):

Akustisch darstellen/beschreiben?